# Does the android-studio tag belong on Super User?

Tags: discussion, tags, off-topic, superuser

Do questions about installing, configuring, and using an IDE qualify as programming related? Or are they more appropriate on the http://superuser.com site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IDE use is appropriate for SO.  Falls under "software tools commonly used by programmers" per FAQ.